# Is it important order of authentication middlewares?

Tags: asp.net-core

When using more than one authentication middlewares, is it important order of these authentication middlewares. For example:

Is there a difference between

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
     //...
});

app.UseIdentity();
```

and

```
app.UseIdentity();

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions()
{
     //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As for any middlewares, the order is important:

> Middleware are software components that are assembled into an application pipeline to handle requests and responses. Each component chooses whether to pass the request on to the next component in the pipeline, and can perform certain actions before and after the next component is invoked in the pipeline

Comment: I am aware of middleware order is important, but i want to know what is difference for authentication middlewares(only). For my example could you show difference between two usages?